# Node base64 upload to AWS S3 bucket makes image broken

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, base64, image-uploading, data-uri

I have a node route that is supposed to upload an image on an AWS S3 bucket, based on a data-uri. Everything works properly, except that the image is broken or not fully uploaded.

Here's my node :

```
router.get('/share', function(req, res, next){

    // Getting the base64 uri from the queried url
    var base64 = req.query.imgUrl;

    // Getting the file type, ie: jpeg, png or gif
    const type = base64.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];

    // Creating a unique key for S3
    const key = uuidv1();

    const buf = new Buffer(base64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'myBucket',
        Key: key,
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: `image/${type}`,
        ContentLength: buf.length,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    // Uploading
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
        } else {
            console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
        }
    });

    res.send('foo');
});
```

The image I get on S3:

[What a mess...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oHYq.jpg)

The image it's supposed to be :

[A magnificent dickbutt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug87i.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your code says that you are encoding your image in base-64 encoding format, and then using aws sdk for nodejs to upload your image to s3. You are actually making a simple thing more complex, aws sdk automatically encodes your image in base-64 encoded format and then uploads it, so you don't need to do it explicitly.

Here is a simple example that does the same thing you want to do :

```
var file = fileChooser.files[0];
if (file) {
    results.innerHTML = '';


    var params = {
         Bucket: 'mybucket'
         Key: 'dated/group1.jpeg',
         ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
         Body: file,
         ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
        }else {
            results.innerHTML = ' snapshot uploaded !!!';
         }
            }).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {console.log(progress);});


} else {

            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
  }
```

Comment: II didn't said that the image I got is not a file or a link, it's a base64 URI that we get from the queried URL (made an edit on my question)