# Broken image from image upload to Amazon s3 via base64 string

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I'm having issues with getting the full image back from amazon s3 after sending a base64 string(about 2.43MB when converted to an image).
[image]
if I compress this image via https://compressnow.com/, and upload, this works fine and I get the full image.

Is it possible for me to compress the base64 string before sending to Amazon s3?

Here is logic to upload to amazon s3

```
await bucket
  .upload({
    Bucket: "test",
    Key: "test",
    Body: "test",
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    Metadata: { MimeType: "png },
  })
```

Similar issue here [Node base64 upload to AWS S3 bucket makes image broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302890/node-base64-upload-to-aws-s3-bucket-makes-image-broken)

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentEncoding` parameter specifies the header that S3 should send along with the HTTP response, not the encoding of the object as far as what is passed to the AWS SDK.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) the `Body` parameter is simply the "Object data".  In other words, you should probably just drop the `ContentEncoding` parameter unless you have a specific need for it and pass along raw bytes:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// Read the contents of a local file
const buf = fs.readFileSync('source_image.jpg')
// Or, if the contents are base64 encoded, then decode them into buffer of raw data:
// const buf = new Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('source_image.b64', 'utf-8'), 'base64')

var params = {
    Bucket: '-example-bucket-',
    Key: "path/to/example.jpg",
    ContentType: `image/jpeg`,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Body: buf,
    ContentLength: buf.length,
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
    } else {
        console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
    }
});
```